# How can I see in my local repository a recently created branches in the Bitbucket repository?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I am just trying to import the branch 'brancTest' recently created in Bitbucket into my local repository.

This is what I am doing  `git checkout -b 'brancTest' origin/brancTest`
And I get this message:

```
fatal: 'origin/brancTest' is not a commit and a branch 'brancTest' cannot be created from it
```

I am in my develop an git status give me this:

```
git status  
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

When I do `git branch -a` I can't see 'brancTest' in the list of all branches.

How to import that branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git fetch
git checkout brancTest
```

Comment: After git fetch I could see brancTest after git branch -a. This command updated the information about the remote repository. It seems that git branch -a do not gram information about the remote repository out there.

Answer (score 0):

Try  "git remote -v" to verify if any remote named 'origin' listed in it.

If you don't find 'origin', that is the remote (which should have been created by default while cloning a repo) is missing.

Add origin again in that case using below:

git remote add origin url/to/your/fork