# git branch --all not showing remote branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a git repo for my dotfiles that I use like so
`100 ~$ git --git-dir=$HOME/.cfg/ --work-tree=$HOME [command]`

When I list my branches I would expect to see another branch `* origin/master` but it does not appear
`101 ~$ git --git-dir=$HOME/.cfg/ --work-tree=$HOME branch --all
* master`

In most other forum posts etc that I found, this was usually solved by adding the remote, but my remote has already been added. `remote show origin` confirms:
`102 ~$ git --git-dir=$HOME/.cfg/ --work-tree=$HOME remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@bitbucket.org:myusername/dotfiles.git
  Push  URL: git@bitbucket.org:myusername/dotfiles.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)`

Also, when I create commits I can push them to master on my remote with no issue. So what exactly is the `origin/master` branch, why is it seemingly automatically present on other local git repos I've worked with, and why is it not in this case?

Edit: I've included some more output from my terminal to clarify what isn't working

`619 ~$ git --git-dir=$HOME/.cfg/ --work-tree=$HOME fetch origin
From https://bitbucket.org/myusername/dotfiles
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
620 ~$ git --git-dir=$HOME/.cfg/ --work-tree=$HOME push origin master
Everything up-to-date
621 ~$ git --git-dir=$HOME/.cfg/ --work-tree=$HOME branch -a
* master
622 ~$ git --git-dir=$HOME/.cfg/ --work-tree=$HOME branch -r
623 ~$`

Comment: To list all branches, use `git branch -a`.  To list only remote branches, use `git branch -r`.  In any case, if you have a local branch called `master` I would wager that `git branch -a` will reveal a tracking branch called `origin/master`.

Comment: make `git fetch` and you'll see remote branches

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142602/how-can-i-see-in-my-local-repository-a-recently-created-branches-in-the-bitbucke

Comment: Running `git fetch` doesn't solve the issue. `git branch -r` shows nothing and `git branch -a` (which is the same as `git branch --all` which I have in my OP) only shows my local branch. I've edited the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix, as torek pointed out in a reply to his answer, was to set remote.origin.fetch. I ran `[git] config --edit` and changed the relevant section from

```
...
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/dotfiles.git
[status]
...
```

to

```
...
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/dotfiles.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[status]
...
```

After this, running `[git] status` informed me that
    On branch master
    Your branch is based on 'origin/master', but the upstream is gone.

Then after running `[git] push` I finally see the remote when I run `[git] status` and `[git] branch -r`

* For simplicity's sake, where I actually ran `git --git-dir=$HOME/.cfg/ --work-tree=$HOME` in my repo, I shortened it to `[git]` in the text above.

Comment: You should mark that as the correct answer. It definitly helped me resolve a similar issue !

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you just need to run:

```
git fetch origin
```

(or even just `git fetch`): call up Git on Bitbucket and have the Bitbucket Git talk with your Git, with them sending things to you.  Or you might need to run:

```
git push origin master
```

which has your Git call up their Git and have a similar talk, in the "other direction".  Your Git sends them any commits you have on your `master` that they don't, and then asks them—politely, "pretty please, if it's OK"—to set their `master` to the same commit that is the tip of your branch.

#### What's going on

Git terminology is confusing.  The name `origin/master` is not a branch name; it's a remote-tracking branch name.  Just as the pair of words "branch name" is often shortened to "branch", the phrase *remote-tracking branch name* is often shortened to "remote-tracking branch".  I have been experimenting with using "remote-tracking name" instead, because remote-tracking names aren't quite branches at all.  In particular, you can't get "on" a remote-tracking name the way you can get "on" a branch ... and while you can have your Git create remote-tracking names directly, you shouldn't.

The *purpose* of these remote-tracking names is for your Git to remember what *their* Git said *they* had, the last time your Git talked with their Git.  So you should have your Git call up their Git.  The two Gits can then talk, and yours can create, update, and even "prune" these remote-tracking things.

Running either of `git fetch` or `git push` has your Git call up another Git.  To do so, your Git needs the URL of the other Git.  Rather than making you type `git@bitbucket.org:myusername/dotfiles.git` all the time, your Git lets you use a short name like `origin`.  (You can choose or change the name; `origin` is just the default you get when you `git clone` by URL, as your clone *origin*-ated from the other Git.)

This short name is a *remote*.  It's also used as the prefix for each of the remote-tracking names, because you can add more than one remote, and *each* Git at *each* URL has its own set of branches, so for your Git to remember the branches at, say, both `origin` and `fred`, you will want your Git to store one memory under `origin/master` and another under `fred/master`.  Of course if you only have one remote, this is overkill, but harmless.

Anyway, `git fetch origin` has them send you all of their branch names, and your Git then downloads any commits they have that you don't, and sets up your `origin/*` names to match their names.  Similarly, `git push origin <name>` has your Git send them commits you have that they don't—new ones you made—and then asks them to set their `<name>` to the same as your `<name>`.  Note that there's no funky renaming here: you ask them to set their *master*, not their `jason/master`.  So push is not quite the exact opposite of fetch, it's just as near as Git gets to the opposite.

#### A side note on `git pull`

What about `git pull`?  Shouldn't `pull` be the opposite of `push`?

Well, not quite: pull was there first, but it turns out to do too much and/or the wrong thing sometimes.  So it got split into `fetch` followed by either `rebase` or `merge`.  After you `git fetch`, you often—but not always—will want to integrate whatever you got from another Git into your own branches.  At this point you will need a second Git command.  Using `git pull` will run both commands for you.  That's essentially all it does, and you *can* do that, but until you're familiar with how each of the various individual commands works—and more importantly, how they *fail* sometimes, and what to do about it—I find it's better to stick with the underlying commands.  Otherwise, `git pull` may have one of the two commands fail, and then you won't know which command failed, much less what to do about it.

Comment: Hi torek, thanks for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately running a fetch or push does not fix the issue. I've edited my OP to show this.

Comment: I suspect your `origin` was added weirdly (did you do something other than `git remote add origin <url>`?) so that the `remote.origin.fetch` default refspec is missing. If this is the case, you'll need to set `remote.origin.fetch` to `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. Because of the asterisks, if you're using a Linux-style shell, you may need to quote the value when using `git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'`, or edit the `.git` config file directly with `git config --edit`.

Comment: You're a wizard! I'm not sure how or why, but remote.origin.fetch was unset, and setting it like you mentioned fixed my issue!